# trying to get all Facebook pages of movies or TV shows

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to run some Facebook API to retrieve pages of movies or TV shows.

If I execute the following to get the page for Seinfeld:
https://graph.facebook.com/9023924452

Then I am trying to check:
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT name, description, type, categories FROM page WHERE page_id = 9023924452
I can see that the type is TV SHOW

The problem is I can use the following FQL to get all those TV SHOWS:
SELECT name, description, type, categories FROM page WHERE type = "TV SHOW"

This fails since the type field is not indexed.

Do you have any alternative idea for me how i can get all the TV SHOWs?

Same I need for Movies.

Thank you very much for your help.

Regards,

Eli.

Comment: just wondering - have you looked into user_interests/user_likes?